Quantum register for variable store - how to encode operations?
Suppose I have a lot of classic variables of a certain number of bits in size, say, 8 bits. Instead of starting each variable from zero in superposition, I want to use the exponential space to encode the variables. What I mean by this is, I don't want separate sets of qubits for different variables - I want to allocate a subspace of superposition to put variables in and use a radix of qubits prefixed at the front to distinguish variables. For example, for the first variable, the radix is zero bits in size so it goes onto the register plain as it does already. For the next variable there is one qubit added to the prefix radix, and the superposition doubles in size so that the next variable can be stored from max(var_1) to max(var_2) + max(var_1) in the superposition. As more variables are added, more prefixes can be added to the radix, incrementally doubling the variable store.
My question is: whenever I want to access a particular one of these subspaces, is it as simple as using the radix number as a control in gates? For example suppose I want to apply gate X to a subspace variable with radix number r. Would that be equivalent to control-X, where the control bits are each bit of the radix r?
Also, suppose the radix contains a zero bit, like 10. To use it in a control, I could just flip before and flip it afterward, right?

Yes to both of your questions

Why didn't you post as an answer instead of a comment? Can you lengthen and provide an example?

You asked two "yes or no" questions, so I gave "yes or no" answers. Not sure what type of "lengthening" you are looking for. If there is something specific you want answered, edit your post above and add it to the original question.
